# Effect of squaring while finding roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, roots-of-unity, paradoxes

Consider $$b=\frac{1}{b}\rightarrow b^2=1$$
Clearly $b=\pm1$   But if we square the above equation on both sides and then solve
$$(b=\frac{1}{b})^2\rightarrow b^2=\frac{1}{b^2}\rightarrow b^4=1
$$
And we know fourth root of unity are $1,i,-1,-i$     why am i getting extraneous roots can someone please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $f(x)=g(x)$ implies $[f(x)]^2=[g(x)]^2$, but not vice versa. More generally, $y^2=z^2$ doesn't imply $y=z$. That's why you wrote $b=\color{blue}{\pm}1$ in the first place.

Comment: if f(x) and g(x) are defined for **real numbers >=0**,(f(x))^n=(g(n))^n,must imply f(x)=g(x) right??